# Getting ERR_CACHE_MISS on window.open

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap (cordova 2.9.1, android 4.4.2) and trying to open an external URL in the current view:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    window.open('http://www.google.com', '_self')

});
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

> net::ERR_CACHE_MISS (http://www.google.com)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The issue ended up being a missing permission, namely, INTERNET permission. 
For some reason I was under the impression that ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE is enough. 
To solve the issue, just add this to *AndroidManifest.xml* :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In my case this permission was enough.

Comment: Do not forget to add the <uses-permission> tag directly into the root <manifest> element - I accidentally added it into the <application> element and it was silently ignored.

Comment: Good call. Just wondering, did it work before you added the permission at some point? I was using this plugin with no problem and all of a sudden I had this error and your answer fixed it. Just curious.

Comment: Yeah it used to work with an earlier version (the app repository stayed the same), I'm assuming it's because of either the Android or the Cordova version change.